# session.gc_maxlifetime not working for me

Tags: php

i want to set session time out limit  by 3 min ,

i have used this in the page

ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime", "50"); **not working**

Solution for this

```
if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 1800)) {
    // last request was more than 30 minutes ago session_destroy();
    // destroy session data in storage session_unset();
    // unset $_SESSION variable for the runtime
}

$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); // update last activity time stamp
```

Comment: define of Not working : means am not get the positive solution , after i used this gc_maxlifetime function ,

Comment: What Pekka actually means is: what result DO you get? How have you tried it? Do you get any error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The session will live as long as the file is left on the server's file system. They are cleaned out by a garbage collector. The garbage collector is run approximately every hundred page loads on the server (this is rather random, the "every hundred" page loads is just an average).

Also, the age of the session is *inactive* age, not total age. The timer will be reset for that session every time the user does a request.

Answer (score 13):

Three variables are used to define the garbage collection behavior of PHP session variables:

1. session.gc_maxlifetime is the lifetime in seconds for the session
   files (default value: 1440 = 24 minutes)
2. session.gc_probability is
   the nominator for the probability to execute the garbage collector
   (default = 1)
3. session.gc_divisor is the denominator for the
   probability to execute the garbage collector (default = 100 or 1000)

The nominator and denominator are used together to determine the probability (nominator / denominator). So when session.gc_probability is 1 and session.gc_divisor 100 this is 1 / 100 = 1 %. So 1 % of every page visit (= every session_start call) the garbage collector is executed.

If you want to test how your session expires, you need to set session.gc_probability and session.gc_divisor to 1, so each page visit will cause the garbage collector to run. Furthermore you need to use two different browsers for the test.
The session of the first browser becomes cleaned when you visit your page with the second browser (and the session of the first browser is timed out). In my tests, when you use only one browser, the session becomes automatically extended although it is outdated.

Comment: Changed session.gc_probability and session.gc_divisor to 1 but no luck. I ran the script mentioned in this stackoverflow question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428153/php-ini-setsession-gc-maxlifetime-5-why-it-doesnt-end-the-session

Comment: @VineetSajwan: The script in that question is wrong. The INI settings here are only evaluated during session_start. In that script of the other question the session is started before the wait time. Furthermore after opening/closing the content of the $_SESSION variable will still be valid for running scripts regardless of this INI settings here.

Answer (score 2):

The unit for the [*session.gc_maxlifetime*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) value is seconds. So you would need to set it to `180` seconds to express 3 minutes.

But besides that, *session.gc_maxlifetime* is not reliable (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes/1270960#1270960) for an explanation). You should better implement that on your own to have your session expired after exactly 3 minutes.