# PHP - ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 5) - Why it doesn't end the session?

Tags: php, session, persistence

The PHP script is as follows:

```
<?php // continue.php
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 5);
session_start();
echo ini_get('session.gc_maxlifetime');
// wait for 7 seconds
usleep(7000000);
if (isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $password = $_SESSION['password'];
    $forename = $_SESSION['forename'];
    $surname  = $_SESSION['surname'];

    echo "Welcome back $forename.<br />
          Your full name is $forename $surname.<br />
          Your username is '$username'
          and your password is '$password'.";
}
else echo "Please <a href=authenticate2.php>click here</a> to log in.";

?>
```

Based on the timeout (i.e. 5 seconds), the script should not print out anything.
However, I still receive the following message

```
5Welcome back Bill. Your full name is Bill Smith. Your username is 'bsmith' and your password is 'mysecret'.
```

It seems that the line ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 5) doesn't work as it should be.
I am using windowsXP + XAMMP.

May you tell me how to make it work?

Thank you

Answer (score 40):

Even if the garbage collector kicked in and deleted the session file you opened/read with `session_start()`, it will NOT reach into the guts of that particular PHP process and delete the `$_SESSION` object array.

Assuming you're on the standard file-based session handler (which contains a `serialize()`'d copy of `$_SESSION`), here's what happens.

1. The session file sits in its temp directory
2. You `session_start()`, causing PHP to open/lock the file, read its contents, deserialize the data, and incidentally, possibly update the session file's "last used" timestamp (atime on Unix boxes).
3. If the stars and moon are aligned correctly with Neptune ascendant in the fifth house, the session garbage collector *MAY* fire up and delete old session files.
4. The garbage collector will happily iterate through the session directory, and delete any files which are older than the max_liftime, **BUT WILL NOT DELETE ANY FILES CURRENTLY OPEN/IN USE**. Since you've not closed()'d your session, your session's file is still in use, so will not get deleted.

Now, if you did something like this:

```
ini_set(...); // set GC probability to max, short session lifetime, etc...

session_start(); // populate $_SESSION
session_write_close(); // dump $_SESSION out to file, close file, release lock.

sleep(7); // Sleep for 7 seconds;

session_start(); // re-populate $_SESSION;
```

Now you might just end up with a fresh blank $_SESSION, **IF** the garbage collector decides to kick in. However, unless you do that second `session_start()`, the old $_SESSION data from the previous start() call **WILL STILL BE PRESENT**. The session file may have been trashed, but the garbage collector will not touch what's present in your script's memory as it runs.

Comment: Are you sure the garbage collector doesn't run *before* `session_start()` populates the `$_SESSION` array?  Do you have a URL that confirms this?

Comment: Doesn't `session_write_close()` update the atime of the file? Then the second `session_start()` would never let the GC delete the file.

Answer (score 9):

session.gc_maxlifetime is the number of seconds after which the session will be ***considered*** for garbage collection.

session.gc_probability and session.gc_divisor then determine the probability that garbage collection will be executed on any session initialization

Comment: Sidenote: I think it's the other way around: It first gets decided if GC should start, then the sessions will be regarded if they should be deleted.

Answer (score 5):

Read the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) (emphasis mine):

> `session.gc_maxlifetime` specifies the number of seconds after which data will be seen as 'garbage' and **potentially** cleaned up. Garbage collection may occur during session start (depending on `session.gc_probability` and `session.gc_divisor`).

In the same page:

> `session.gc_divisor` coupled with `session.gc_probability` defines the probability that the gc (garbage collection) process is started on every session initialization. The probability is calculated by using `gc_probability/gc_divisor`, e.g. 1/100 means there is a 1% chance that the GC process starts on each request. `session.gc_divisor` defaults to 100.

Now do the math and see that it's not very likely the GC will be called on each request.

You should store the in the session a variable that saves the time of the last activity of the user and use that instead of the session is logically "active". Don't rely on garbage collection.

Comment: I think the point here though is that the session is still active, and thus should probably not be subject to garbage collection in any case. I don't know for sure though.

Comment: @Pekka The point is that garbage collection is useless here because 1) it will only be called with a small probability and 2) it's only called on `session_start`.

Comment: agreed. Plus, garbage collection is even more useless because the session we're in is still active (and some internal handler presumably locked). Correct?

Comment: @Pekka Well, I'm not sure about that, I'd have to check the sources and it's already late :p But I hope so!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is how `gc_maxlifetime` is supposed to work. The manual says

> session.gc_maxlifetime specifies the number of seconds after which data will be seen as 'garbage' and **potentially** cleaned up.

(emphasis mine)

in your case, the session is still active. Therefore, I don't think it will be subject to garbage collection.

You could try doing a  `session_write_close()` before the sleep(). That might increase the probability that the garbage collector.

Comment: He we had the same idea on the emphasis :p

Comment: @Artefacto yeah, how funny! :)

Comment: Hello all,

I added the following lines, but it still doesn't work.

ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 5);
ini_set('gc_probability', 100);
ini_set('gc_divisor', 100);

what I want to do is to enforce the session automatically expired after 5 seconds. If this method doesn't work, how to make it work?

thank you

Comment: @q0987 Garbage collection would runs (potentially) when calling `session_start`.

Comment: Plus @q0987 @Artefacto a session that is still in use *is not garbage* at all, is it? @q0987 you should probably think about a different approach to this, e.g. by storing a `$_SESSION` value with a time stamp, updating that on each request, and checking whether the session value and the current time are more than x seconds apart.